# Multithreading - Synchronizing the block for all instances of an Object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class as Calculate. I created two threads both working on different instances of this class and tried to get the value of i. But both are giving me same values.

I want if one thread of a instance is working then the thread working on other instance should wait.

```
public class Calculate {
    private int i=2;
    public  void showNumber(){
        synchronized(Calculate.class){
            i=i+2;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"Value of i is "+i);
    }
}

class Test1 implements Runnable{
    Calculate c=null;
    public Test1(Calculate c){
        this.c=c;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" Running");
        c.showNumber();
    }

}
public class ThreadingPractise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculate c=new Calculate();
        Calculate c1=new Calculate();
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Test1(c),"t1");
        Thread t2=new Thread(new Test1(c1),"t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you make things wait/block? What piece of code should wait?

Comment: Here I am creating two instances of Calculate class and both threads are working on seperate instances, so i am getting same value of variable i. But i want if one thread is working then other thread of other instance should get the updated value

Comment: everywhere I am getting that if u acquire the lock at the class level then the synchronized block will be accessed by one thread for every instance of that object.
Refer to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206732/how-to-make-a-method-synchronized-across-all-instances-of-an-object

Comment: My making the `i` field non-static you have specified that each instance should have it's own value.  BTW synchronized only protects the code inside the block.  When you print `i` there is no guarantees.

Comment: You are right about a synchronized block on a class, but that is not your problem.

Comment: @Peter...then if i make i Static then is there any need of Synchronization? so if i write synchronized(Calculate.class) then it will make sure that this block is modified by one thread only even if n number of instances are created..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `i` as static. If you want to share the variable between threads. and synchronize showNumber method instead of Calculate.class so that only 1 thread will run it at a time.

Comment: By using static it is working fine. I not understanding the concept. By having synchronized method only the threads working on one instance can be stopped. But how  to make a method synchronized across all instances of an object.

Comment: when you create new instance. each instance will have it's own i value. It is not shared between threads which owns it;s own instance. Synchronzation comes in picture only if you are sharing data between threads. you can read java tutorials about threading to understand this concept very well.

Comment: @Naruto...so if i write synchronized(Calculate.class) then it will make sure that this block is modified by one thread only even if n number of instances are created?? Can u make this point more clear...

Comment: ,...Can you please explain more..I understand that two threads working on same instance will be blocked by synchronized but how to make sure that two threads on different instance should also be synchronized?

Comment: yes when you synchronize the class. It will be used by one thread irrespective of instances. but in your case though it will be used by one thread at a time. Each thread will modify it's own instance's i. because i is not shared.

Comment: Thanks for your response..now can u lastly tell me how to make i shared between threads. This will make my concept clear...if i use static then without synchronize also it gives me updated value..

Comment: If u make i as static then i is class variable not instance variable. so it is shared between multiple instances. as each thread owns it's own instance , they all will share the same i.  so you need to synchronize operations that modifies i.

Comment: @Naruto..to be more precise I want i to be shared between t1 and t2 which work on two different instances of Calculate class.

Comment: @Naruto..I made i as static but even without using synchronized the other thread is getting the updated value. Can you tell me why?

Comment: yes because class variables are shared between instances , those will be shared among threads which has instance of Calculate class.

Comment: If one thread changes value of shared data , it gets affected on all  threads.  that's the purpose of sharing.

Comment: Sorry but i am lost here...then what is the use of making the method synchronized if the threads are getting updated values?

Comment: Also then why did you mentioned to make i as static and then synchronize the block which modifies i.??